# How to iterate through each row in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query returns 26 table names.

```
select name from sys.tables where name like '%JPro_VP_Service%'
```

Now I'm trying to write a query to check in every table return from the above query.

```
--consider this is my first table 
select * from JPro_VP_Service 
where row_id like '%1-101%' or row_id like '%1-102%'
-- likewise I want to search in 26 tables return from above query
```

I think I need to write for or cursor to accomplish this.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like your data model could use some re-design. If that is the same data in those table, it should be stored in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is
Try this:

```
SELECT 'select * from ' + name 
       + ' where row_id         like ''%1-101%'' or row_id like ''%1-102%''' 
FROM   sys.tables 
WHERE  name LIKE '%JPro_VP_Service%'
```

you will get all tables together with the same conditions. You could execute them together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to use a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) for this, and probably also [dynamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Also see

[Generate dynamic SQL statements in SQL Server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306)

[Dynamic SQL PROs & CONs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/transactsql/thread/e697a3d6-8811-463d-8624-6c9ec370a8eb)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mn INT 
DECLARE @mx INT 
DECLARE @tblname VARCHAR(100); 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn, 
                name 
         FROM   sys.tables 
         WHERE  name LIKE '%JPro_VP_Service%') 
SELECT @mn = Min(rn), 
       @mx = Max(rn) 
FROM   cte 

WHILE( @mn >= @mx ) 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @tblname = name 
      FROM   cte 
      WHERE  rn = @mn 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   @tblname 
      WHERE  row_id LIKE '%1-101%' 
              OR row_id LIKE '%1-102%' 

      --Do something else 
      SET @mn=@mn + 1 
  END
```

Comment: `cte` can only be used in the clause `SELECT * FROM @mn=Min(rn), @mx=Max(rn) FROM cte`. When `cte` is used in the while loop, the sql server reports an error

Answer (score 0):

This route may work, though you might want the results saved to a table:

```
DECLARE @tables TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tables (Name)
SELECT name 
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name like '%JPro_VP_Service%'

DECLARE @b INT = 1, @m INT, @table VARCHAR(100), @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @m = MAX(ID) FROM @tables

WHILE @b <= @m
BEGIN

SELECT @table = Name FROM @tables WHERE ID = @b

SET @cmd = 'select * from ' + @table + '
where row_id like ''%1-101%'' or row_id like ''%1-102%''
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd

SET @b = @b + 1
SET @cmd = ''

END
```